# how would you say “i killed death”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

i used to know but can’t recall the exact translation i wanted.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide more context? _Mortem interfeci_ looks like a good literal translation. But it seems you are looking for a specific passage with that meaning. Christian literature has developed the image motivated by Christ's resurrection, e.g. in the Easter Sequence: _Mors et vita duello conflixere mirando/Dux vitae mortuus regnat vivus_

Answer (score 6):

At least Luther wrote (WA 56,323,19-24):

> Quia Mortem occidi est mortem non reverti [...]

Clumsy translation: "For Death to be killed is death to not return..."

We could modify that phrase so that "I killed Death" = *Mortem occidi*. Funnily enough the first person perfect looks identical to the passive infinitive.